# c# How to upload multiple files to SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, upload

Given:

1. c# WinForms application
2. more than 1000 `.txt`, `.pdf`, `.doc` files
3. SQL Server 2008 table

   ```
   create table docs
   (
       id int not null identity primary key,
       filename nvarchar(255),
       filecontent varbinary(MAX),
       filetype nvarchar(10),
   )
   ```

I know how to upload file by file using `INSERT` or `MERGE`, but it is a long operation.

How to effectively fast upload many files into the table?

Comment: Are you using ADO.NET or Entity Frame work or LINQ?

Comment: use SqlBulkCopy operation so that you can insert multiple records faster.

Comment: Ok, add your answer and I will mark it.

Comment: But the question is: how to read from source when SqlBulkCopy using? I understand if the source is another table but what if it is file directory ?

Comment: so in this case use DataTable in C# at source.

Comment: Ah, you mean read N files into DataTable then do BulkCopy, and so no. Ok, I see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84166/discussion-between-naveen-nikhil-and-oleg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use SqlBulkCopy operation so that you can insert multiple records faster.